# Повтор обработки событий в Java

Tags: java, javafx

Есть кнопка, при нажатии на которую проигрывается звук и меняется цвет. Как через время возвращать кнопке первоначальный цвет и добавить возможность много раз нажимать на кнопку?

```java
Number6.setOnAction(event -> {
    PSTriple.play(); // PSTriple - медиафайл
    Number6.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red");
    Number6.
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Запустите таймер, по истечении которого верните кнопку в нужное состояние:

```
private static void returnButtonState(final Button button, long delay) {
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //логика с кнопкой
            timer.cancel();
        }
    }, delay, 1000);
}
```

Пример вызова:

```
Number6.setOnAction(event -> {
PSTriple.play(); // PSTriple - медиафайл
Number6.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red");
returnButtonState(Number6, 3*1000); //вызовется 1 раз через 3 сек
```

Comment: UI работает в отдельном треде, и изменение состояния приведет к непредсказуемому поведению и исключениям (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22772379/updating-ui-from-different-threads-in-javafx)

Answer (score 1):

Вариант с использованием [Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html):

1. В обработчик события добавляем вызов метода:

   ```java
   laterRepaint(300);
   ```
2. Сам метод:

   ```java
   private void laterRepaint(int delay) {
       Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
          try {
             Thread.sleep(delay);
          } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
             e1.printStackTrace();
          }
          // ... действия с кнопкой ...
       });
       thread.start();
   }
   ```